# Pass parameter to default controller/method with Yii urlManager

Tags: .htaccess, yii

I would like to use a catch-all rule for urlManager that would pass anything after my base url to a default controller and method as parameters.

My goal would be for a url such as `mysite.com/123` to map to `mysite.com/controller/method/123` where controller/method are predetermined and `123` is passed as a named parameter.

Such a rule would be put last in the urlManager chain so that if none of the other rules match it would pass whatever is after the base url to my selected controller/method.

Any ideas??

**Edit:**
Adding a rule `'<id>'=>'controller/method'` (which I think I had tried anyhow) and then viewing site.com/123 would return a 404 not found, but from *apache*, NOT Yii. Something I did not take into consideration.

Going to `mysite.com/index.php/123` got the desired result. Going to `mysite.com/controller/method` though would route the url properly. Strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to put this as the last rule under all other rules.

```
'<id>' => 'controllerName/methodName/<id>,'
```

---

**Example:**

```
'<id>' => 'user/view/<id>',
```

This will redirect all URLs like this:

```
mysite.com/1
```

To:

```
mysite.com/user/view/1
```

If you want to restrict  to numbers only, use

```
'<id:\d+>' => 'controllerName/methodName/<id>,'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this rule to bottom of url rules:

```
 'urlManager'=>array(
  'urlFormat'=>'path',
  'rules'=>array(
     '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
     '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
     '<pname:\w+>'=>'site/test',
  ),
),
```

Pname: your named parameter.
Site/test: the target action.

In your action you should define your "pname" as method paramter:

> ```
> public function actionTest($pname) {
>     echo "Name:$pname";
> }
> ```